# Regular expression to return modified string in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like below

```
**102-Gracecroft-Dr_Havre-de-Grace_MD_21078_M60846-99581**
```

I want to remove the last part which starts with M and digits which will be dynamic values. So the result string should be like

```
"**102-Gracecroft-Dr_Havre-de-Grace_MD**"
```

How can i achieve it using regex.
i tried with `[/.*(?=[/d+]_M[\d-]+)/]`

But it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: The removed "last part" actually starts with `_M` and the "dynamic values" contains a `-` in addition to digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
▶ str = "102-Gracecroft-Dr_Havre-de-Grace_MD_21078_M60846-99581"
#⇒ "102-Gracecroft-Dr_Havre-de-Grace_MD_21078_M60846-99581"
▶ str[/.*(?=_M[\d-]+)/]
#⇒ "102-Gracecroft-Dr_Havre-de-Grace_MD_21078"
```

If the asterisks are indeed parts of the real input:

```
▶ str = "**102-Gracecroft-Dr_Havre-de-Grace_MD_21078_M60846-99581**"
▶ str.gsub /_M[\d-]+(?=\*{2}\z)/, ''
#⇒ "**102-Gracecroft-Dr_Havre-de-Grace_MD_21078**"
```

Comment: I want to exclude 21078 also. Sorry. I typed the resultant string wrongly. It should be "102-Gracecroft-Dr_Havre-de-Grace_MD"

Comment: This is easily achievable basing on snippet I have provided. Left as a homework.

Comment: I tried with the below one. .*(?=[/d+]_M[\d-]+) But it dint work either. Any suggestions

Comment: You have a typo (forward slash instead of back slash, and there is underscore to take into account, and `+` should not be disclosed within square brackets...) It should be `.*(?=_\d+_M[\d-]+)`.

Comment: @ mudasobwa. But this returned me 102-Gracecroft-Dr_Havre-de-Grace_MD_2107. excluding only '8'. I want to exclude 21078 also.

Comment: I have provided the regexp in my last comment.

Comment: Yes. I got it with .*(?=_\d+_M[\d-]+)